# How large of a capacitor is needed to hold 5,000,000,000 J?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, capacitance, estimation, lightning

Given today's technology, what size of capacitor (in farads and physical size) would be required to hold 5,000,000,000 J of energy, the estimate for the amount of energy in the average lightning bolt?

Answer (score 2):

The very latest supercapacitor technologies could in theory (it's a long way from an actual product) store [180Whrs per kilogram](https://www.theengineer.co.uk/supercapacitors-battery-technologies/). Actual supercapacitors you can buy right now manage about 10% of that.

So a supercapacitor capable of storing the $5$ gigajoules in a lightning bolt would weigh about $8$ tonnes at the currently experimental limits or about $80$ tonnes if you wanted to store that energy right now.

Answer (score 0):

This will require 100 copies of what is presently [the largest capacitor bank in the world](https://www.quora.com/How-many-Farads-does-the-largest-capacitor-ever-made-have-And-whats-its-purpose), at the Hochfeld-Magnetlabor Dresden (HLD).

Comment: be careful not to touch the capacitor terminals, otherwise you would die exponentially.